# Importar un xls o csv sin modelo Django

Tags: django, excel, csv

He estado investigando y no encuentro la manera de importar un archivo ya sea `xls` o `csv` sin tener un modelo, estoy tratando de importar a la base de datos archivos de este tipo pero los mismos podrian variar en numero de columnas inesperadamente hay forma de hacer lo que necesito ? solo necesito que me apunten a la direccion correcta

Comment: ¿Tienes que "importalo" a base de datos campo por campo?, sino, lo que yo haría es tener un modelo con un campo de archivo `FileField()` y subir tus archivos con este modelo, luego cuando necesites la información, podrías leer el archivo en una vista y le sacaría los datos necesarios.

Comment: A ver si entiendo y disculpa mi ignorancia pero soy nuevo en Django, debo crear un modelo de esta manera `class modelo(models.Model): data = forms.filefield()` y mi archivo quedaria entero en la base de datos?, interesante no sabia que se podia hacer (necesito los datos de esos archivos para hacer graficas para los usuarios)

Comment: Te dejé en una respuesta la forma de hacerlo, si te sirve comentame, buena suerte.

Comment: Disculpa no haber respondido, no solo me sirvió para mi proyecto, entendí mas sobre el tema, muchas gracias por tu ayuda fue un gran aporte

Comment: Un placer que te haya gustado, si te fue útil sería bueno calificar como correcta la respuesta que puse. Espero que sigas aprendiendo mucho.

Comment: Listo, es que no sabia que eso se podia tambien soy nuevo en el foro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de guardar el archivo en base de datos es la siguiente:

```
class modelo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    archivo = models.FileField()
```

y luego creas una vista donde captures los datos del formulario enviado y guardas el archivo. Hay que aclarar que esto no guarda el archivo en base de datos, esto lo sube a tu carpeta "media" y guarda en base de datos la referencia hacia ese archivo.

Cuando lo hayas subido, puedes acceder a este y leerlo en python normalmente (en una vista).

También puedes hacerlo con un modelo que hereda de los formularios de Django:

```
from django import forms

class formulario_csv(forms.Form):
    titulo = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    archivo = forms.FileField()
```

En este caso sería lo mismo, solemente que al guardarlo lo procesas como un formulario. Te dejo la documentación de Django para subir archivos:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/